# Documenting fake classes

Tags: c++, lua, doxygen

I have a function which exposes all of my required C++ functions to Lua, there are various tables representing different aspects of my "Scripting API", what I wish to do is use doxygen to make a scripting reference using the C++ code that exposes these script functions.

I have tried to make 'fake' classes in the body of the function, which successfully makes a new entry with the name I have given it, for instance if I make a table named 'Math' which has several functions exposed on it, how would I also make 'fake' member functions in this 'fake' class, I have tried to simply pass in \fn defining the function, however it does not show up as they are not actually real members to add a description to. How would I create this sort of effect in doxygen without hand righting a verbatim definition of every class, but instead treat the comment block as if it were a real class with real members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a fake .doxy file which had typenames similar to lua values, apparently doxygen will document any type to throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to document Lua code as if they were C++. Maybe it's possible, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

If you're trying to document Lua code with doxygen, maybe you could try [doxygen-lua](https://github.com/alecchen/doxygen-lua).

If your Lua API is small, you could just write a page by hand, with \ref's to the relavent C++ code. (Kind of hacky, but I've done this before.)

You could also consider using some other doc generator for your Lua API, such as [LuaDoc](http://keplerproject.github.com/luadoc/), or anything else listed on the lua-users wiki [DocumentingLuaCode](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DocumentingLuaCode).